# Search button not working html

Tags: html

I have a search box with a button next to it, if i type something into the search box and hit enter it will do a search, but not if i just click on my search button, anyone know why?

```
<ul class="searchListUl">
   <li>
      <form>
         <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Keywords" required>
            <select class="region">
                <option value="1" selected>example</option>
                <option value="2">example</option>
            </select>
            <select class="department">
                <option value="a" selected>All Departments</option>
                <option value="b">Computing</option>
            </select>
         <input type="button" class="button" value="Search">
      </form>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share your js code also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace type `button` with `submit`

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Search">
```

Comment: @RhysE96 No problem, I´m glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrived here wondering why the `button` element is not submitting their form, note: The button element works *identically* to `input type="submit"`, but *only* if you include the `type="submit"` attribute on it.

This will submit your form:

`<button type="submit">Go</button>`

This will not:

`<button type="button">Go</button>`

Answer (score -1):

That seems awesome. But you can simply use the button tag in html.

```
<button type="button">Search</button>
```

This seems a much easier way to do it.

Comment: Using `type="button"` will not submit your form when clicked. `<button type="submit">` will submit your form.

Answer (score -2):

it is actually:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

did you see that fa fa-search I devoloped a a cool kind of button